# NSMutableUrlRequest keeps failing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, laravel

I'm a complete newbie to the concept of a server backend connected to an iOS app, but thought I should know some more about it. I created the function below with the help of some tutorials on the internet. However, when this is executed I keep getting an error message (500, eventhough when I test the same url with my webapp it works). Does anyone know what's causing this?

```
- (void)loadNinjas {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.load.com/ninjas"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];
    [mutableRequest addValue:_xAuthToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];

    request = [mutableRequest copy];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;

        NSMutableArray *tempNinjas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray) {
            Ninja *ninja = [[Ninja alloc] initWithDictionary:dic];
            [tempNinjas addObject:ninja];
        }


        self.ninjas = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempNinjas];
        tempNinjas = nil;

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Services"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

And this is an example of the JSON it fetches:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "name" : "test1",
            "text" : "test1test1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "test2",
            "text" : "test2test2",
        },
        {
            "name" : "test3",
            "text" : "test3test3",
        }
    ]
}
```

The request goes to a Laravel route:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth.token'], function ()
{

    Route::resource('ninjas', 'ApiController'); 

});
```

And this is the function it calls:

```
public function index()
{

    $payload = Request::header('X-Auth-Token');

    $check = AuthToken::validate($payload);

    $userid = $check['id'];

    $ninjas = DB::table('ninjas')
                ->where('userid','=', $userid)
                ->get();

    return $this->respond([

        'data' => $this->NinjasTransformer->transformCollection($ninjas)

    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lines that say:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.load.com/ninjas"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];
[mutableRequest addValue:_xAuthToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];

request = [mutableRequest copy];
```

You can simplify that to just:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.load.com/ninjas"]];
[request addValue:_xAuthToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
```

You are also initiating both `NSURLConnection` as well as AFNetworking request. I'd pick one or the other (AFNetworking is probably going to be easier). So eliminate the line that says:

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Regarding why you're receiving the 500 status code, we don't have enough information to diagnose that. You can try monitoring successful connection via [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and then comparing that to what you see when Charles monitors your app trying the same connection.

But we don't have enough information to diagnose what precisely your web service needs/expects.

Comment: Could it be the JSON it fetches? I added it to the question.

Comment: No, it's something else, probably a result of how the request is formed. But we don't know what the request is supposed to look like for your particular server, so it's hard for us to say.

Comment: I added the code from the server to my question, since I'm starting to get desperate for this problem to be solved.

Comment: OK. So how confident are you of the `_xAuthToken` value? I'd still be inclined to compare working solution vs app with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com).

Comment: Before reading your comment and installing Charles, I tried a simple NSLog on _xAuthToken and as it turns out I forgot to name a segue, which prevented the value from being sent to this controller. Thanks for the help :)